# hmacsha1 encrpyt in vba does not equal to php hmac_sha1 value with pack method

Tags: php, vba, encryption, vb6

This is my VB6 Code

```
Private Function Encryp_HMACSHA1(pData As String, pSecretKey As String) As String
Dim encoder  As Object
Dim crypto As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim bSecretKey() As Byte
Dim bData() As Byte
Dim bEncrypted() As Byte

Set encoder = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set crypto = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

bData = encoder.Getbytes_4(pData)
bSecretKey = encoder.Getbytes_4(pSecretKey)
crypto.Key = bSecretKey
bEncrypted = crypto.ComputeHash_2(bData)


Set encoder = Nothing
Set crypto = Nothing

Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

objNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
objNode.nodeTypedValue = bEncrypted
EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

Encryp_HMACSHA1 = EncodeBase64

Set objNode = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

End Function

Public Function Pack(strlength As String) As String
Dim Temp As String
Dim MyString As String
Dim i As Integer

MyString = ""
For i = 1 To Len(strlength) Step 2
    Temp = Mid(strlength, i, 2)
    MyString = MyString & Chr(CLng("&H" & Temp))
Next

Pack = MyString
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim pKey As String
   pKey = Pack("1989151498577ad12a9f8adf157f5abf")
   Text1.Text = Encryp_HMACSHA1("test", pKey)
End Sub
```

result for vb is : `03AM+k4B3mPEZlkCatDvdiHOuuc=`

This is my php code

```
$key = "1989151498577ad12a9f8adf157f5abf";

$decodeKey = pack("H*",$key);

$data = "test";

$hash = hash_hmac("SHA1", $data, $decodeKey, TRUE);

$signature = base64_encode($hash);


echo $signature;
```

result for the php is : `4QXpNBD/cv0sLIfFIsFGe5D57gI=`

Please help in solving the equation.
And There is another problem, If we encrypt the data without pack method both are the outputs are same, but if we does with pack it shows different results.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VB6 `Pack` function is:

- converting two hex digits at a time to bytes, then
- converting those values to characters with ANSI-to-Unicode translation.

Then your `Encryp_HMACSHA1`:

- takes such String values and converts them into Byte arrays using conversion to UTF-8, and
- feeds that into `crypto.Key` to munch on.

Playing fast and loose using Strings in this manner has corrupted your key value.

I was apply to reproduce the incorrect signature result by taking known-working VB6 code and altering it to perform the same distortion.

I'm not sure why you are using this great big heavy .Net inter-clop approach to doing part of the job and then taking another really heavy run through an MSXML DOM just for Base64 encoding.  Wow, do you have enough RAM for this to even run?

I used the `HS1.cls` from the attachment (`HS1 Demo 1-1.zip`) at:

[[VB6] HMAC-SHA-256, HMAC-SHA-1 Using Crypto API #35](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?635398-VB6-HMAC-SHA-256-HMAC-SHA-1-Using-Crypto-API&p=4326461&viewfull=1#post4326461)

Then all that was required was:

```
Private Function HMACSHA1(ByVal Data As String, ByVal Key As String) As String
    With New HS1
        .InitHmac .Decode(Key, edfHexRaw)
        HMACSHA1 = .Encode(.HMACSHA1(.ToUTF8(Data)), edfBase64, efNoFolding)
    End With
End Function
```

Where Data is VB6/Windows "Unicode" text (UCS-2/UTF-16LE) and Key is a "Unicode" string of hexadecimal text.  E.g.:

```
txtSignature.Text = HMACSHA1("test", "1989151498577ad12a9f8adf157f5abf")
```

Sure enough, it produces:

```
4QXpNBD/cv0sLIfFIsFGe5D57gI=
```

This is also far lighter weight than using (a.) the .Net CLR and Framework libraries plus "interop" and (b.) MSXML as super-fat wrappers around simple API calls.

But you could keep all of that overhead if you really want to as long as you correct your "String of hex digits to Key" parsing logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,your answer is perfectly worked, you made my day.    I obliged

Answer (score 0):

If `"1989151498577ad12a9f8adf157f5abf"` is supposed to be the key in hexadecimal the php code is correct.

Verify if `Encryp_HMACSHA1` expects the key to be data or a hexadecimal string.
Verify if the keys after conversion to data are the same by displaying them in hex

Comment: If we encrypt the data without pack method both are the outputs are same, but if we does with pack it shows different results.   Please suggest some solution

Comment: As stated in the answer, the PHP code produces the correct hash.You need to figure out what needs to be changed in the VB6 implementation, closely looking at the documentation for the expected input formats should help.